# Converting a character range to int

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Suppose we have a character range:

```
// For example
const char *valueBegin="123blahblah"; // Beginning of value
const char *valueEnd=valueBegin+3;    // One past end of value
```

..., and I want to convert it to an int:

```
int value=...// Given valueBegin and valueEnd, calculate 
             // the number stored starting at valueBegin
```

What are some good C++11 ways to do that?

Obviously you can create an `std::string` and use `stoi`, or copy it to a temporary NUL-terminated character array and then it's easy (e.g., via `atoi` or `strtol`).

Think about a way that doesn't involve copying the characters to some temporary array/object - in other words a function that works on the character data in-place.

**Update**:

Lots of answers, but please think before you answer. The range is not `NUL` terminated, hence the need for `valueEnd` . You don't know what is beyond the value (i.e., perhaps valueEnd is beyond the buffer containing the value), so if your answer does not use `valueEnd`, it is wrong. Also, if your answer creates a temporary `std::string` object, it is not within the guidelines of this question.

Comment: *sEnd does not point to a null...

Comment: Are you specifically not interested in using `sscanf`?

Comment: Yes trying to avoid `sscanf` with a length specifier. I was hoping for a C++ solution if possible.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Just curious, whats the advantage of this? Your using a c-style string, in c++11... Is this just a code-gulf style of game, or does it actually serve a purpose? (Just not understanding, and I hate missing an opportunity to learn.)

Comment: Real world production code that does any sort of I/O with the external world and interoperates with legacy (perhaps old C or bad C++) libraries is often faced with situations such as this - the need to convert a character string containing a number somewhere in the data as part of parsing.

Comment: Ok, I will try and write up a solution different than what is already there. Doubt it will be any good, but sounds like fun. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: As is often the case in C++ - a simple question with a not so simple answer :) .

Comment: Too true.. Just not sure what else to do off the top of my head besides an external library (e.g. boost), a number converter, or existing c++ functions. I will still try though, not sure how successful I will be in creating a better optimized version.

Comment: I was hoping for a pure C++11 solution that uses existing functions/algorithms. This is what makes this question difficult, but I am sure it can be done, perhaps in a not so obvious way.

Comment: @rootix converting sub-ranges of a packed buffer of characters into values is a very useful operation.  Using an object like `std::string` for parsing is not practical, as sub-strings require copies.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<int>(sBegin, 3) << std::endl;
```

This does not create any temporaries and supports any kind of character range. It's also quite [fast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html).

If you want to avoid the length specifier then you can use `boost::iterator_range`:

```
std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<int>(boost::make_iterator_range(begin, end)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: The first answer that actually answers the question, +1 for now.

Comment: I should mention that the only two negatives to this solution are the possibility of an exception being thrown and a dependency on an external library (i.e., boost). However, because I already have a boost dependency and the exception handling overhead is most likely negligible on just about any modern optimizing compiler, this answer suits my actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

Without any error checks, this seems simple enough.

```
int number = 0;
for ( char* cp = valueBegin; cp != valueEnd; ++cp )
{
   number += number*10 + (cp-'0');
}
```

If you need to want to stop at the first non-digit,

```
int number = 0;
for ( char* cp = valueBegin; cp != valueEnd && isdigit(*cp); ++cp )
{
   number += number*10 + (cp-'0');
}
```

If you need to be able extract negative numbers and be able to gracefully deal with leading `+/-` signs, the code will become a little bit more complex.

```
int number = 0;
char* cp = valueBegin;
int sign = 1;
if ( *cp == '-' )
{
   sign = -1;
   ++cp;
}
if ( *cp == '+' )
{
   ++cp;
}

for ( ; cp != valueEnd && isdigit(*cp); ++cp )
{
   number += number*10 + (cp-'0');
}
number *= sign;
```

Comment: This if filed under the _roll your own number converter_ I was trying to avoid. But I'll give you a +1 nevertheless, because it is at least within the constraints of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Boost and don't mind needing to copy the digits to a temporary string, you can do this with `std::stoi`:

```
std::cout << std::stoi(std::string(valueBegin, valueEnd)) << std::endl;
```

There's other converters for different numeric types as well - `stol`, `stoul`, `stoll`, `stoull`, `stof`, `stod`, `stold`.

These are defined in C++11.

(Personally, I would take the Boost option, but some people might not want the additional dependency.)